# How to show part of image as background in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background

Assuming I have some large images, also I have a 98*98 div and want to show the center part of the image as a thumbnail, i.e., center width*width for portrait or height*height for landscape and scale to 98*98. I have the following PHP and HTML code

```
<?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize($thumbpath);
if ($width > $height) {
  $heightnew = 98;
  $widthnew = 98 * $width / $height;
} else {
  $widthnew = 98;
  $heightnew = 98 * $height / $width;
}
$thumbcss = ' style="background: url(\'' . $thumbpath . '\') no-repeat;' . 
            ' background-size: ' . $widthnew . 'px ' . $heightnew . 'px;' .
            ' -moz-background-size: ' . $widthnew . 'px ' . $heightnew . 'px;' .
            ' background-position: 50% 50%;';
echo '<div class="thumb"' . $thumbcss . '></div>';?>
```

It works fine in all advanced browsers, except IE8. Then I try to add the following to the CSS: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=\'' . $thumbpath . '\', sizingMethod=\'scale\'); -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=\'' . $thumbpath . '\', sizingMethod=\'scale\');`, but what it does is scale the entire image instead of the scaled center.

Is there a way to deal with the **__** IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Give that div background of that image: background:url(pathtoimage.ext) no-repeat center;